# What are the endpoints in piecewise functions?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the critical points of this piecewise function:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-x^2-9x+7 \quad \text{for} \quad x \le 1 \\
-x^2+4x-6 \quad \text{for} \quad x > 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

**My question is**: Does $x=1$ count as an endpoint?

This is my first time encountering piecewise functions when calculating local extreme values so I'm not too sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $x = 1$, calculate the slope of the first function and the slope of the second function.  The slope of the first is negative, and the slope of the second is positive.

Next, determine if the piecewise function is continuous at this point (it is).  Therefore, the point at $x = 1$ is a local min.  It is also a critical point.  A critical point occurs whenever the derivative of your function is zero or undefined (the case here, since the derivative is different approaching from left and right of $x = 1$).

Comment: that makes so much sense thank you.